# How to parse JSON .net web service to Android properly?

Tags: android, asp.net, json, web-services

I have tried many versions of parsing the JSON data from my .net web service and my current one
adds a {"d": ..... in front of my JSON data and i have no idea why.

When invoke my webservice manually , the data is in the correct format.
However when i use this parser , i have checked usin .names() to list out the names of JSONObjects , and it only shows ["d"]

Is there any recommened codes to parse JSON webservices in java?

Heres my code to parse the data

```
        //initialize
                InputStream is = null;
                String result = "";
                JSONObject jArray = null;
                String url = "http://10.0.2.2:1672/Eventurous/WsEventurousMobile.asmx/getEventsList";
                //http post
                try{

                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                    obj.put("category",category);
                    httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString(),"UTF-8"));

                    httppost.setHeader("Accept","application/json");
                    httppost.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();

                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                }

                //convert response to string
                try{
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    result=sb.toString();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                }

                //try parse the string to a JSON object
                try{
                        jArray = new JSONObject(result);
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                }

                try{

                        JSONArray catalogObj = jArray.getJSONArray("Table");
   //Im using the newtonsoft json dataset converter and so the name of the JSONArray
       //is by default Table and i have no idea how to change it either

                        JSONObject event = catalogObj.getJSONObject(0);
                        return event.getString("EventName");        

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    return e.toString();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the gson lib, http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/.

> Is there any recommened codes to parse JSON webservices in java?

Without knowing the json data, it's hard to give any concrete advice. But anyhow, I recommend to use the gson lib, which is quite popular amongst Android developers.

Comment: the d variable is apparently a security feature of .net

I made a work around by getting the data in the d variable , reparsing it as the "correct" response of the web service as a JSONObject.


What I did

Object JSONdata  =  jArray.get("d");
jArray.getJSONArray("Table");
JSONObject catalog = new JSONObject(JSONdata.toString());
JSONArray catalogObj= catalog.getJSONArray("Table");
JSONObject event = catalogObj.getJSONObject(0);

Comment: Anyway thanks for the response. Ill keep it in mind. For now I dont think I will need it since it working.

Comment: Ok, I see. But then the question isn't really Android specific nor client specific, as it's just a server-side issue, while the returned json is actually valid; suggest to remove the Android tag. "When invoke my webservice manually, the data is in the correct format." Do you mean the server returns differing json responses? How do you invoke the web service manually?

Comment: Never mind, after a few Bing searches, like Cory Tam mentioned, it is the normal behavior of the .Net web services. And to handle that and to get the right Json string i did this 

JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(httpResponse).nextValue();
   
String jsonString = jsonObject.getString("d");

Hope, this helps somebody who consumes the Asp.Net web service that returns Json.